# Angular filedownload spinnerService

Tags: angular, typescript

I am downloading a large volume file and while downloading the spinner.show it just displayed for few seconds and then disappeared.

I want to show the spinner wheel till the file downloaded is complete.

I am using Angular 5 version, below is the typescript code snippet.

```
filedownload() 
{
    let byteArray = [];
    this.serviceArray.forEach(function (service) { byteArray.push(service) });
    let _formdata = { selectedyear: this.Serviceyear };
    this.spinnerService.show();  //NgxSpinnerService
    let downloadname = "Books.xls";
    this.downloadService.booksdownload(_formdata).subscribe(
    result => {
        if(result._body.length !==0)
        {
            var fileblob = new Blob([result._body], {type: "application/octet-stream" });
            var fileurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileblob);
            var fileelement = document.CreateElement('fileelement');
            document.body.appendChild(fileelement);
            fileelement.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            fileelement.href = fileurl;
            fileelement.download = downloadname;
            fileelement.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileurl);
            fileelement.remove();
        }   
        else {          
            alert("Unable to download file");
        }
        }, error => {
            this.spinnerService.hide();
        }, () => {
            this.spinnerService.hide();
    });
}
```

Please help me whether I need to make any change in the code or any other options available.

Comment: Move `this.spinnerService.hide();` inside brackets where your processing the blob. It might take a while for the blob to be converted to an fileelement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems unable to do so, but you could keep your spinner until the Blob was created.

wrap your new Blob into another observable or promise

then handle your `this.spinnerService.hide();` in the nested resolve or subscribe.

```
return new Observable(() => {
           return new Blob([result._body], {type: "application/octet-stream" });
}).subscribe(
    result => {
    // start your download
});
```